# Concurrency-safe SQL query for removing codes from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

I'm designing an API that provides unique codes to clients from a table. Each request should return a unique code from the table, or an error if there are no more codes available. I want to ensure that each request gets a new code, with no codes being reused. Preferably this would flag codes as used with a boolean attribute, rather than deleting them. This is being stored in a MySQL database, but ideally I'd want a portable solution that uses standard SQL.

Currently, what I've worked out is the following (simplified, there are other fields/foreign keys, etc.):

```
-- Schema for the code table
CREATE TABLE reward_code (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
    in_use tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

-- Checking for a code and marking it as used in a single transaction
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM reward_code WHERE in_use = 0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE reward_code SET in_use = 1 WHERE id = <id>;
COMMIT;
```

This appears to work, as a second transaction started between the `SELECT` and `COMMIT` will wait for the first to complete, and then return the next available row from the `reward_code` table, as the first one is now marked as used.

However, I'd like to avoid locking rows if possible. Is there a non-locking way of doing this?

Comment: My car appears to be able to drive on wheels.  However, I'd like to avoid wheels if possible.  Is there a non-wheel way to drive my car?

Comment: @Andomar There are ways of accomplishing similar tasks without locking rows. For example, it's possible to decrement a counter safely across multiple threads/processes by using UPDATE and checking the rows affected.

Comment: @Andomar Are you saying that it's impossible, or do you think I should rephrase the question? Thanks.

Comment: If you could update without a lock, you could corrupt the database.  So no, that should not be possible.